# Get attributes from one line feature to another

Tags: arcmap, line

I have to use two different networks (e.g., Network A and Network B) to do analysis and they don't align with each other perfectly. I used the same points to split the lines in the two networks, so each line in the Network A can find another corresponding line in the Network B, as shown in the figure[image]. How can I get some attributes from the red line between the black triangle points to the green line?

I am using ArcGIS Advanced License Desktop 10.3.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this in several ways. The simplest would be to use the Spatial Join (Analysis) tool. This will join the attributes of one line feature class to the geometry of the other. Chose JOIN_ONE_TO_ONE under 'Join Operation' and CLOSEST under 'Match Option'. This will give each new line the attributes of the one line closest to it.

Comment: Thanks. It works partly. The two networks have a different number of roads, which means when I use the Spatial Join, some of the roads might get closest lines from another network, which should not happen?

Comment: Which network has more roads? I thought in your original question you said each line has a corresponding line in the other network.

Comment: Network A has more links, and I want to get data from it and put them on network B. Right now the best results I can have is to use Spatial Join (HAVE_THEIR_CENTER_IN), but there are still places I need to manually correct. For example, highways, where there are 2 links in network A, but only 1 link in network B. Anyway, your method helps me a lot.